# How to get load html with Ajax and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquerymobile.  I have a page that gets the latest posts with a click on a refresh button.

I can't get any html from viewposts.php to show up in the #test div.

```
$("#refresh").click(function(){        
            $.ajax({  

               cache: false,
               url: "mobile/viewposts.php", 
               success: function (html) {
                    $("#test").append(html);
                    $("#test").fadeOut(1000);
                    alert(html);
                }


            });
```

I have tried with dataType: 'html', and type: 'POST', and GET.
Tried with $("#test").html(html);

The fadeout works. The alert is blank.

The view posts page gets the latest posts from the DB.  I'm also echoing some random html in the viewposts.php.

I'm able to do an ajax call and get the html if i don't use jquery.  The problem is that way the html thats returned doesn't use the jquerymobile stylesheet so it just looks like plain text.

I'm new to this.

Please help.

```
<div data-role="page" id="readBlogPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Read Blog</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <!--<button onclick="ajaxFunction()" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="refresh" >Refresh</button>-->

        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#createNewPostPage" id="cancel" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">New Post</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="refresh" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="refresh" type="submit">Refresh</button></div>
        </fieldset>

        <!--<button onclick="ajaxFunction()" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="refresh" id="refresh" type="button">refresh</button>-->
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-inset="true" id="ajaxout">



        </ul>
        <div id="test" >asdfsadfsd</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Viewposts.php echoes a bunch of lines like this

```
echo "<li><h3 style=\"margin:0px;\">" . $ row['post_title'] . "</h2>" . $row['post_content'] . "<p class='ui-li-aside'>Lat: ". $row['lat'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;Lon: ". $row['lon'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;" .$row['post_date'] . "<strong></p></li>";
```

This is the response header in firebug

```
Response Headers
Date    Sun, 03 Jul 2011 17:38:20 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.1.6
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Expires Sun, 03 Jul 2011 17:38:20 GMT
Content-Length  0
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Pad   avoid browser bug
```

Comment: it might be a case of html encoding. did you mean **plain text** as in something like `<a href="http://google.com">go to google<a>` when you wanted just a link that looks like [go to google](http://google.com)?

Comment: I'm not sure you mean.  The viewposts returns a bunch of <li> rows.  How do i do plain text?  At this point i would like at least something to show up when i click the refresh button.

Comment: could you show the implementation of that and the html page you are getting?

Comment: added the html.  As you can see there is a button commented out that calls ajaxfunction().  That button works fine, but it doesn't use jquery.

Comment: Ideally I would like to insert the returned html into UL #ajaxout and have it show up properly styled.   In the above code i'm just trying to output to the test div below.  All I see is that div fadeout.

Comment: @vtpets: Have you tried using Firebug's console to see what the AJAX call looks like? If so, are you getting a response back?

Comment: Nothing shows up in chrome but in firefox console i see ...mobile/viewposts.php?_=some-random-13digit-number  200 OK . Nothing shows up under HTML tab and Reponse tab is blank as well

Comment: @vpets: I was asking what does your page looks like inside #ajaxout. I would like to see exactly what ajaxout displays. please mark your answers with @naveen so that i may see those earlier

Comment: @naveen: inside ajaxout is just a bunch of list items.  Exactly like the echo line pasted above. Not sure if i'm answering your question.  I can't even get simple "hello world" text to show up.

Comment: @vpets: Could it be your PHP code? I don't know PHP so I can't help with that part, but 200 OK means that your server is being contacted successfully. The random number at the end of the URL is jQuery attempting to receive a fresh page (instead of a cached one).

Comment: try replacing the `function (html) {
                    $("#test").append(html);
` with `function (data) {
                    $("#test").append(data);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically from what I can see (please correct me if I am wrong) you trying to put the HTML that you get form the viewposts.php file into the  $("#test"),

Your trying to do this:

```
functionn(html){

 $("#test").append(html);
}
```

Jquery Ajax returns: data, so try:

```
function(data){
$("#test".append(data);
}
```

[Jquery Ajax documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I got it to work with (data).  I still have an issue with the content not being styled properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a `Content-Length` of 0. Is that normal ?